# How to get a user-configurable buffer for printing?

Tags: perl, buffer, filehandle

I'd like to have a print function supporting a user-configurable buffer, so to print what I have in the buffer only when the buffer is > a threshold).

I need to write multiple files, so I have multiple filehandles to write to, and for this an object oriented module might be handier.

I imagine something like this:

```perl
my $printer1 = Print::Buffer->new({ size => 1000, filehandle => \$OUT1 });

for (my $i=1; $i<1000; $i++) {
 $printer1->print("This string will be eventually printed ($i/1000)");
}
# and at the end print the remaining buffer
$printer1->flush();
```

Any recommendation? I probably don't use the right keywords as with print/buffer I didn't find clear matches in CPAN.

**UPDATE:**
Thanks everyone for the very useful comments. As some of  you pointed out, the problem is more complex than I initially thought, and probably a bad idea. (This question arose as I was printing very large files [>100Gb] in with a print statement at each loop iteration, and noted that if I was printing every hunderth iteration I had a speedup, but it could be dependent on how the loop was changed...)

**UPDATE 2:**
I need/want to accept an answer. To me both have been instructive and they are both useful. I tested both and they both need further work before being able to benchmark the improvement (if any, see update above). The *tie* handle is a less known feature that I loved, that's why I accepted that. They were both equally close to the desired answer in my opinion. Thank you all very much for the discussion and the insights.

Comment: File handles are buffered by default. Though I think they are line buffered instead of having a fixed size buffer.

Comment: Interesting, but yes my aim is to print only after collecting a biggish chunk of data (dozens Mbs).
In my implementation, this speeds up the process that is I/O limited

Comment: By default, STDERR is unbuffered, STDOUT is line buffered *if* it is connected to a terminal, and other file handles have a fixed size buffer (8K on my system)

Comment: I think that after downvoting one could spend 10 seconds commenting, so that I can try to rephrase the question in a better way

Comment: The downvotes are probably because you are asking for recommendations, which isn't the purpose of Stack Overflow.

Comment: For the record, you could try https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlIO::buffersize

Comment: Thank you @Grinnz, helpful for both

Comment: But i think the opinion based problem arise when you ask "what is the better way". I found NO way to do what I needed... but I'll close the question in any case.

Comment: Note the unbuffered [syswrite](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/syswrite.html), which you could leverage in your own utility wrapper/method.  Do read and heed warnings about not mixing it with buffered operations.  I think the question is reasonable, even if it may benefit from improvement in description; voted to reopen.

Comment: Allocate a variable for data, start to print into this variable (`sprint` or `pack` for example), monitor pointer until buffer is full then automatically flush data into filehandle or write your own flush subroutine to call it when it is required.

Comment: @Brad Gilbert  Re "*File handles are buffered by default. Though I think they are line buffered instead of having a fixed size buffer.*", File handles except STDOUT and STDERR are block buffered by default.  STDERR isn't buffered. STDOUT is line buffered if connected to a terminal, or block buffered otherwise.  (Note that each PerlIO layers may have its own buffer, so adding an encoding layer to STDERR will effectively cause it to become buffered.)

Comment: Re "*8K on my system*", It was hardcoded at 4 KiB until 5.14. Since 5.14, it can be configured when `perl` is built, defaulting to 8 KiB.

Comment: @Grinnz, Note that PerlIO::buffersize [doesn't work](https://pastebin.com/Uktz698n) if you also use `:encoding`

Comment: @ikegami Try with the `:encoding` layer first? And please [open a bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Dist/Display.html?Name=PerlIO-buffersize)

Comment: @Grinnz, Re "*Try with the :encoding layer first?*", 8 KiB chunks. /// Re "*And please open a bug*", There's no point. This isn't something fixable. Each layer can have its own buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a general solution on CPAN, either. But this is straightforward enough with tied filehandles. Something like

```
use Symbol;
sub Print::Buffer::new {
    my ($class,$mode,$file,@opts) = @_;
    my $x = Symbol::gensym;
    open ($x, $mode, $file) or die "failed to open '$file': $!";
    tie *$x, "Print::Buffer", fh => $fh, @opts;
    $x;
}

sub Print::Buffer::TIEHANDLE {
    my $pkg = shift;
    my $self = { @_ };
    $self->{bufsize} //= 16 * 1024 * 1024;
    $self->{_buffer} = "";
    bless $self, $pkg;
}

sub Print::Buffer::PRINT {
    my ($self,@msg) = @_;
    $self->{buffer} .= join($,,@msg);
    $self->_FLUSH if length($self->{buffer}) > $self->{bufsize};
}

sub Print::Buffer::_FLUSH {
    my $self = shift;
    print  {$self->{fh}}  $self->{buffer};
    $self->{buffer} = "";
}

sub Print::Buffer::CLOSE {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->_FLUSH;
    close( $self->{fh} );
}

sub Print::Buffer::DESTROY {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->_FLUSH;
}

#  ----------------------------------------

my $fh1 = Print::Buffer->new(">", "/tmp/file1", 
                             bufsize => 16*1024*1024);

for (my $i=1; $i<1000; $i++) {
    print $fh1 "This string will be eventually printed ($i/1000)\n";
}
```

Comment: Seems kinda silly to use `print`, which sends the data out in lines or [8 KiB chunks](https://pastebin.com/yz4FqDbe). `syswrite` could be used. As a thin wrapper over the `write` system call, if anything is going to output the data in the specified block size, it's the one. (It might not, though. It can write less than requested, so it could take multiple calls to print out an entire buffer.) The down side of using `syswrite` is that you can't use stuff like `:encoding` with it.

Comment: Probably missing something like `open my $fh, $mode, $file || die;`in the constructor, but nice example! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for catching that, Andrea T.

Answer (score 3):

> I'd like to have a print function supporting a user-configurable buffer,    [...]
>   I imagine something like this:     [...]

It's not hard to write something like it.  Here's a basic sketch

File `PrintBuffer.pm`

```
package PrintBuffer;

use warnings;
use strict;

sub new { 
    my ($class, %args) = @_; 
    my $self = { 
        _size => $args{size}       // 64*1024,            #//
        _fh   => $args{filehandle} // *STDOUT,
        _buf  => ''
    };  
    $self->{_fh}->autoflush;  # want it out once it's printed
    bless $self, $class;
}

sub print {
    my ($self, $string) = @_; 
    $self->{_buf} .= $string;
    if ( length($self->{_buf}) > $self->{_size} ) { 
        print { $self->{_fh} } $self->{_buf};
        $self->{_buf} = ''; 
    }
    return $self;
}

sub DESTROY {
    my $self = shift;
    print { $self->{_fh} } $self->{_buf}  if $self->{_buf} ne ''; 
    $self->{_buf} = ''; 
}

1;
```

There's a bit more to do here, and a whole lot that can be added, and since it relies only on basic tools one can add/change as desired.<sup>†</sup> For one, I can imagine a `size` method to manipulate the buffer size of an existing object (print if there's already more data than the new size), and `flush`.

Note that `DESTROY` method provides for the buffer to be printed as the object drops out of any scope, and is getting destroyed, what seems reasonable to do.

A driver

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use PrintBuffer;

my $fout = shift // die "Usage: $0 out-file\n";

open my $fh, '>', $fout  or die "Can't open $fout: $!";

my $obj_file   = PrintBuffer->new(size => 100, filehandle => $fh);
my $obj_stdout = PrintBuffer->new(size => 100);

$obj_file->print('a little bit');
$obj_stdout->print('a little bit');
say "printed 'a little bit' ..."; sleep 10;

$obj_file->print('out'x30);                 # push it over a 100 chars
$obj_stdout->print('out'x30);
say "printed 'out'x30 ... "; sleep 10;

$obj_file->print('again...');               # check  DESTROY
$obj_stdout->print('again');
say "printed 'again' (and we're done)";
```

Check the size of output file in another terminal after each informational print.

I tried [PerlIO::buffersize](https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlIO::buffersize) brought up by Grinnz in a comment and it seems to work "as advertised" as they say. It doesn't allow you to do all you may wish but it may be a ready solution for basic needs. Note that this doesn't work with `:encoding` layer in use.

Thanks to ikegami for comments and tests (linked in comments).

---

<sup>†</sup> The `print` works with an `autoflush`-ed handle. Still, the first change could be to use [syswrite](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/syswrite.html) instead, which is unbuffered and attempts to directly write all that's asked of it, via one `write(2)` call. But since there's no guarantee that all got written we also need to check

```
use Carp;  # for croak

WRITE: {
    my $bytes_written = 0;
    while ( $bytes_written < length $self->{_buf} ) {
        my $rv = syswrite( 
            $self->{_fh}, 
            $self->{_buf}, 
            length($self->{_buf}) - $bytes_written,
            $bytes_written
        );
        croak "Error writing: $!" if not defined $rv;
        $bytes_written += $rv;
    }
    $self->{_buf} = '';
};
```

I've put this in a block only to limit the scope of `$bytes_written` and any other variables that one may wish to introduce so to reduce the number of dereferences of `$self` (but note that `$self->{_buf}` may be quite large and copying it "to optimize" dereferencing may end up slower).

Naively we'd only need `syswrite(FH, SCALAR)` but if it happens that not all of `SCALAR` gets written then we need to continue writing from past what was written, thus the need to use the form with length-to-write and offset as well.

Since this is unbuffered it mustn't be mixed with buffered IO (or that need be done very carefully); see the docs. Also, `:encoding` layers can't be used with it. Consider these restrictions against other capabilities that may be wanted in this class.

Comment: Seems kinda silly to use `print`, which sends the data out in lines or [8 KiB chunks](https://pastebin.com/yz4FqDbe). As you mentioned earlier, `syswrite` could be used. As a thin wrapper over the `write` system call, if anything is going to output the data in the specified block size, it's the one. (It might not, though. It can write less than requested, so it could take multiple calls to print out an entire buffer.) The down side of using `syswrite` is that you can't use stuff like `:encoding` with it.

Comment: Note that PerlIO::buffersize [doesn't work](https://pastebin.com/Uktz698n) if you also use `:encoding`

Comment: @ikegami "_kinda silly to use `print`, which sends the data out in lines or [8 KiB chunks](https://pastebin.com/yz4FqDbe)_"  -- absolutely, that's one of the first things to improve, but since it needs a little loop (as it may not write all as asked etc) I opted for simplicity.  Should've at least commented though -- thank you.

Comment: @ikegami Added these as comments/code, thank you again